# VBA - Graph by month

Tags: vba, excel

I am having issues trying to create code to make a graph that is dependent upon months.  So I have `Column A` which is the beginning of the week date, i.e. 1/1/17.  In `Column B` I have the count from that week of issues occurred.  I would like to group together the count by month, using the `Month` function, so for January there are 37 issues, February - 23, etc.  And then make a graph accordingly where the first month is titled January.

Eventually, I would  like to similarly do this on  a quarterly basis as well, but any help with the monthly issue first would be greatly appreciated.  Here is a screenshot of the data which is located in `Worksheets("Report")`.

[image]

Comment: Please read [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513) -  Also: [mcve].

Comment: @Mat'sMug - I just need some help to get started with some code.  I don't know where to start that's my issue.

Comment: @A.Cohen before trying to jump into VBA, get familiar with the different options within Excel first. I made months of mistakes that I learned were mistakes through short youtube videos. Check out `Excel Dashboards` on Youtube for a great springboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, format your data as a table since that will make your life much easier. You will need to add headers to each column. This will make your data easier to read, and easier to maintain.

To format it as a table highlight the range, and then press CTRL+T. Make sure to check 'My data has headers'.

Good, now click inside the table, `Insert > PivotTable`. Select the destination. For rows you want `Date`, for values you want `Sum of Value` (where value is whatever you name your values column.

Then finally, check out this article for the whole rundown of Groupby: http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot07.html.

To be fair, there is an easy enough way of doing this without a PivotTable (adding a helper column for `Month` for example), but there's no need to reinvent the wheel. Additionally, if you want to add `Qtr.` eventually, you're better off familiarizing yourself with workhorses of excel.

Lastly, once you have taken the above steps, you'll likely find the `Timeline` slicer very helpful. You can use that to visualize specific periods on your pivot or chart.

Minor Note: This all assumes your dates are true dates. If they aren't, you'll likely run into more issues.